# No puedo hacer un correcto uso de ClipPath en flutter

Tags: flutter

Quiero hacer lo siguiente en flutter:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no consigo entender como funciona ClipPath, ya leí todo el material de flutter y vi vídeos en Youtube.

esta es mi clase:

```
class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 40);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width/4, size.height, size.width/2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width-(size.width/4), size.height, size.width, size.height-40);


    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Si hay alguna otra forma de lograr este diseño se agradece info.

PD: Otra forma puede ser hacer una imagen jpg en Photoshop?

Por ejemplo si quiero que es ves del efecto bottom lo haga en top tambien como deberia de hacer?

```
class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 20);

    var firstControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height);
    var firstEndPoint = Offset(size.width / 2.25, size.height - 30.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);

    var secondControlPoint =
    Offset(size.width - (size.width / 3.25), size.height - 65);
    var secondEndPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - 40);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
        secondEndPoint.dx, secondEndPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 40);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

[image]

Este es el resultado final: (primer foto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODIGO:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      //BLOQUEAR ROTRACION DE PANTALLA
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);

    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        home: Scaffold(
          body: HomePageBody(),
        ));
  }
}

class HomePageBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageBodyState createState() => new _HomePageBodyState();
}

class _HomePageBodyState extends State<HomePageBody> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    //SPLASH SCREEN
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30), //3
        () {
      Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage());
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //PLASH SCREEN
    return new Scaffold(
      //appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 80,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blueAccent, //Tema.Colors.appBarGradientEnd,
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "¡Bienvenidos!",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  letterSpacing: 0.8,
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 180
            ),
            child: Image.asset(
              'fotos/fondo.jpg',
              width: 600.0,
              height: 240.0,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
          ClipPath(
              clipper: MyClipper(),
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 500.0,
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 60.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 20);

    var firstControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height);
    var firstEndPoint = Offset(size.width / 2.25, size.height - 20.0);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy, firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);

    var secondControlPoint = Offset(size.width - (size.width / 3.25), size.height - 55);
    var secondEndPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - 30);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy, secondEndPoint.dx, secondEndPoint.dy);


    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: y como has declarado el widget que usa ese Clipper ?

Comment: @diegoveloper ClipPath(
              clipper: MyClipper(),
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 580.0,
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 60.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              )),

Answer (score 0):

Podrías estructurar tu layout de otra forma, así :

```
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  height: 120.0,
                  child: Text("Bienvenidos"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text("Imagen aquí"),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: MyClipper(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 70.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("Parte inferior"),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

Comment: Si le saco el margen sube el container arriba de la pantalla. Al inicio

Comment: Ahí edite la publicación.... con la foto de como queda

Comment: entiendo, lo quieres poner abajo, revisa mi código actualizado

Comment: o en todo caso, puedes poner un screen de como quieres que quede la pantalla,  y también poner el código completo que usas

Comment: ahí añadí de como quiero que quede la pantalla

Comment: Ahí puse el código diego

Comment: revisa mi código actualizado, hice un ejemplo básico que te puede ayudar

Comment: Gracias Diego por tu tiempo, igualmente sigo sin comprender como funciona el ClipPath y como hacer el efecto de la imagen que mostré de como tiene que quedar....

Comment: el ClipPath solo realiza un corte de acuerdo al Path que le asignas, en este caso está cortando el Container,  si se te complica puedes usar este package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/wave